# Most Pythonic way to find which of a set of inputs, when fed to a function, produces the smallest output

Tags: python

I have a list of objects object_list and a function func. I want to find which object produces the smallest output from func. Currently my code looks like this:

```
minimum_object = object_list[0]
minimum_value = func(object_list[0])
for object in object_list[1:]:
     val = func(object)
     if val < minimum_value:
         minimum_value = val
         minimum_object = object
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to solve this problem? I feel like my solution is really verbose, for a problem that should be solved with one call to a magic high level function from itertools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid calling the function again after finding the minimum object, convert object_list into a list of `(value,object)` tuples, and take the min of that:

```
min_value, min_obj = min((func(obj), obj) for obj in object_list)
```

If there is a chance that there might be multiple objects with the same min value, use sort and groupby:

```
first_element = operator.itemgetter(0)
sorted_objects = sorted(((func(obj),obj) for obj in object_list), key=first_element)
minvalue,mintups = next(itertools.groupby(sorted_objects, key=first_element))
minobjs = [tup[1] for tup in mintups]
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
minimum_object = min(object_list, key=func)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
minimum_object = min(object_list, key=func)
minimum_value  = func(minimum_object)
```